# Get the datepicker looks like the ones provided in Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I would like to get a datepicker in WindowsForms as compact as the one provided in the Windows Task Scheduler :
[image]

Is it a hidden option of the Calendar, or is it a custom development ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it with two date/time pickers  -one for date, one for time.  (Mine may look different based on my Desktop Theme - Windows Classic)

[image]

- The date one has the Format property set to "Short".
- The time one has the Format property set to custom, and the CustomFormat set to hh:mm ttso it would read "12:00 PM".  You can change the format as you like.

Then in code, I combine the two to come up with a full DateTime.

```
 DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue;
 try
 {
    dt = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.Add(dateTimePicker2.Value.TimeOfDay);

 }
```

Comment: Ahh.. OK.  I'll look into that as well.  Unless someone else beats me to it.  Then I'll delete this answer.

Comment: I don't see that as an option using it natively, or using built-in controls.  It could be made as a Custom Control using a button (for the image) and a MonthCalendar control, but there isn't a control for this in the System.Windows.Fomrs section of the class library.  I'm sure there are custom controls, and ActiveX controls like that as well, but that doesn't meet your criteria for "natively".